# PHP Variable Produces Correct String but throws JSON error

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

I created the following script which produces a string I later use in a JSON response. However, it throws an error despite it being formatted correctly. What is strange is if I copy the output of the variable directly into the script it works just fine.

```
    $vls_minidbqs = 'Apples;Oranges;Bananas'
    $vls_dbqs = explode(";", $vls_minidbqs);
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[0])) {
    $dbq0 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[0].'\",\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq0 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[1])) {
    $dbq1 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[1].'\",\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq1 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[2])) {
    $dbq2 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[2].'\",\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq2 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[3])) {
    $dbq3 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[3].'\",\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq3 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[4])) {
    $dbq4 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[4].'\",\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq4 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[5])) {
    $dbq5 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[5].'\",\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq5 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[6])) {
    $dbq6 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[6].'\"\,\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq6 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[7])) {
    $dbq7 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[7].'\",\r\n ';;
      }else{
    $dbq7 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[8])) {
    $dbq8 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[8].'\",\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq8 = '';
    }
    if (!empty($vls_dbqs[9])) {
    $dbq9 = '\"'.$vls_dbqs[9].'\",\r\n ';
      }else{
    $dbq9 = '';
    }
    $vls_dbqs = '\r\n '.$dbq0.''.$dbq1.''.$dbq2.''.$dbq3.''.$dbq4.''.$dbq5.''.$dbq6.''.$dbq7.''.$dbq8.''.$dbq9.'';
    $vls_dbqs = substr($vls_dbqs, 0,strrpos($vls_dbqs,","));
    $vls_dbqs = $vls_dbqs.'\r\n';
```

This code produces the following string:
\r\n "Apples",\r\n "Oranges",\r\n "Bananas"\r\n

JSON epects the following. Whats strange is if I copy and paste the string directly into the code it goes or remove the variable it goes through no problem:
\r\n "Apples",\r\n "Oranges",\r\n "Oranges"\r\n

All other variables I am passing are working. Is it an encoding issue?

Here is the PHP/CURL code I am using (the section in question "Fruit": [$vls_dbqs],\r\n):

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\r\n\t\"data\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"Owner\": {\r\n                \"name\": \"XXXXXXXX\",\r\n                \"id\": \"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\r\n                \"email\": \"XXXXX@XXXXX.com\"\r\n            },\r\n            \"Mailing_State\": \"$vls_mailingstate\",\r\n            \"Affiliate\": \"XXXXXXX\",\r\n            \"Mailing_Apt_Unit\": \"$vls_apt\",\r\n            \"Services_Needed\": \"$vls_servicesneeded\",\r\n            \"DBQ_State\": \"$vls_mailingstate\",\r\n            \"Vet_also_Service_Connected_for\": \"$vls_alsosc\",\r\n            \"Affiliate_Email\": \"XXXXX@XXXXX.com\",\r\n            \"Mailing_Street\": \"$vls_mailingstreet\",\r\n            \"Co_Owner\": {\r\n                \"name\": \"XXXXXXXXX XXXX\",\r\n                \"id\": \"2922631000001654004\"\r\n            },\r\n            \"Full_Name\": \"$vls_first_name $vls_last_name\",\r\n            \"Disability_7\": \"$vls_disability7\",\r\n            \"Disability_8\": \"$vls_disability8\",\r\n           \"Disability_3\": \"$vls_disability3\",\r\n            \"Disability_4\": \"$vls_disability4\",\r\n             \"Disability_5\": \"$vls_disability5\",\r\n            \"Disability_6\": \"$vls_disability6\",\r\n            \"Veteran_Review\": \"$vls_veteran_review\",\r\n            \"Overall_Rating\": \"$vls_overallrating\",\r\n            \"Fruit\": [$vls_dbqs],\r\n            \"Vet_Overseas\": \"No\",\r\n            \"Layout\": {\r\n                \"name\": \"Standard\",\r\n                \"id\": \"2922631000000091033\"\r\n            },\r\n            \"Lead_Source\": \"VetLink Solutions\",\r\n            \"Disability_1\": \"$vls_disability1\",\r\n            \"Disability_2\": \"$vls_disability2\",\r\n            \"Email\": \"$vls_email\",\r\n            \"Vet_Right_or_Left_Handed\": [\r\n                \"$vls_dominatehand\"\r\n            ],\r\n            \"ITF_Date\": \"$vls_itf\",\r\n            \"Multi_Select_3\": [\r\n                \"$vls_gender\"\r\n            ],\r\n            \"Mailing_Zip\": \"$vls_mailingzip\",\r\n            \"First_Name\": \"$vls_first_name\",\r\n            \"Phone\": \"$vls_phone\",\r\n                        \"Date_of_Birth\": \"$vls_dob\",\r\n            \"Mailing_City\": \"$vls_mailingcity\",\r\n            \"Middle\": \"$vls_middle_name\",\r\n            \"SSN\": \"$vls_ssn\",\r\n            \"Expedite2\": \"No\",\r\n            \"Last_Name\": \"$vls_last_name\",\r\n            \"Account_Status\": \"XXXXXX - New Client\"\r\n        }\r\n    ]\r\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken $refresh_token",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: A json string doesn't need to have those line breaks and tabs. But instead of trying to manually generate the json data yourself, just create an array with the correct format and run it through [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn it to valid json. Way easier and less error prone.

Comment: your code is really to bad to run

Comment: Use this 2 lines of code to convert it into json ```$arr = array('Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'four');
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);```

Comment: @NalinNishant Thank you, this did the trick. I knew I was taking the long way around the bus on this one. Thanks for the response!